# Spring Websocket mutiple broker relay addresses?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-websocket

I have a cluster of RabbitMQ servers.  I want to load balance my StompBrokerRelay requests from my spring boot application (with websockets) to the nodes across the cluster, BUT i don't see where I can set a list of addresses with the MessageBrokerRegistry.  Right now the configuration looks like this:

```
  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config
        .enableStompBrokerRelay("/exchange")
        .setAutoStartup(true)
        .setVirtualHost(BROKER_VHOST)
        .setRelayHost(BROKER_HOST)
        .setRelayPort(BROKER_PORT)
        .setClientLogin(BROKER_CLIENT_LOGIN)
        .setClientPasscode(BROKER_CLIENT_PASSWORD)
        .setSystemLogin(BROKER_SYSTEM_LOGIN)
        .setSystemPasscode(BROKER_SYSTEM_PASSWORD);
  }
```

Is there some way to .setRelayHosts() or do I need to look for another framework or, heaven forbid, try to finagle this stuff into working with multiple hosts.

Comment: Why not use rabbitmq cluster?

Comment: I plan to.  The problem is the client needs to detect failures.  From the documentation:

"A client can connect as normal to any node within a cluster. If that node should fail, and the rest of the cluster survives, then the client should notice the closed connection, and should be able to reconnect to some surviving member of the cluster."

So if spring doesn't allow you to specify multiple hosts, i'm not sure what to do when one fails.

Comment: Has this been resolved now? I need to add multiple brokers(activeMQ as well as rabbitMQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible right now.  Spring websocket is sort of half-baked.

Comment: is this still not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-stomp-handle-broker-relay-configure. If you wish to supply multiple addresses, on each attempt to connect, you can configure a supplier of addresses, instead of a fixed host and port. Code Snippet also included at the end of the section.